# XML Unit showing similar XML as false

Tags: xml, assert, xmlunit

```
    XML1:
    <record>
        <record name="technicalEnvelope" javaclass="XXX">
          <value name="flowReferenceId">xyz</value>
        </record>
        <record name="functionalEnvelope" javaclass="XXX">
          <value name="flowReferenceId">abc</value>
        </record>
    </record>
    XML2:
    <record>
        <record name="functionalEnvelope" javaclass="XXX">
          <value name="flowReferenceId">abc</value>
        </record>
        <record name="technicalEnvelope" javaclass="XXX">
          <value name="flowReferenceId">xyz</value>
        </record>
    </record>

    Diff myDiff = new Diff(XML1, XML2);
    assertTrue("pieces of XML are similar " + myDiff, myDiff.similar());
```

Comparison fails for these two similar XML due to different order.
Any help/guidance would he highly appreciated.

Comment: I believe that xmlunit needs the sorted xml as input.

Comment: Thanks Rao for your comment but sorting will not help me here as one xml gets generated at runtime which is being compared with expected xml.

Comment: Had similar problem some time ago, so what i did was pass the runtime generated file and static file to a program which did the sorting, then pass that out put another utility like xmlunit for comparison. But that was for a specific type of xml, not for generic xml.

Comment: Thanks Rao ...
I found a solution which I have posted below.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Diff myDiff = new Diff(myControlXML, myTestXML);
    myDiff.overrideElementQualifier(new ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier());
    assertTrue("pieces of XML are similar " + myDiff, myDiff.similar());
```

Comment: Glad to know. But this may not work if you have more complex elements.

Answer (score 0):

For more complex elements you will need to tell XMLUnit how to identify the elements you want to compare with each other.  This is exactly `ElementQualifier`'s job.  There are a bunch of built-in implementations of `ElementQualifier` (like `ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier` used by Hoshang) but if neither of them fits your requirements, you'll need to implement the interface yourself.